# A question in calculating a constant in section square free values of quadratic polynomials

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I am studying square free values of quadratic polynomials from class notes and I  am struct on a deduction.

Consider this conjecture, I have no problem in understanding it:

[image]

Consider this theorem, I have no problem in understanding it.
[image]

But I have problem in calculating $c_f$

[image]

I don't understand , how author wrote $\rho(p^2) = 1+ (-1/p) $.

Kindly consider giving any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)$ appears to be using the [Legendre symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol). Using your question's Lemma $2.2$, plus what's stated in [The first supplement to the law of quadratic reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol#Properties_of_the_Legendre_symbol) (in the $7$'th bullet point), then with odd primes $p$, if $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$, then $\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right) = 1$ (so $1 + \left(\frac{-1}{p}\right) = 1 + 1 = 2 = \rho(p) = \rho(p^2)$), and if $p \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$, then $\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right) = -1$ (so $1 + \left(\frac{-1}{p}\right) = 1 - 1 = 0 = \rho(p) = \rho(p^2)$).